# ListView EditTexts values are messed up when scrolling

Tags: android, listview, android-edittext

As I mentioned in the title, the listview duplicates edittexts values for the children after i=10 in the for loop in my code.

```
public class ExerciseAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<ExerciseSet> {
    private ArrayList<ExerciseSet> mExercise;
    private LayoutInflater inflater;

    private List<String> texts = new ArrayList<String>();

    public ExerciseAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId, ArrayList<ExerciseSet> objects) {
        super(context, textViewResourceId, objects);
        mExercise = objects;
        inflater = (LayoutInflater) getContext().
                getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemViewType(int position) {
        if(mExercise.get(position).isSet() == false) return 0;
        else return 1;
    }

    @Override
    public int getViewTypeCount() {
        return 2; // two types of rows, exercise headers and bodies (sets)
    }


    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent){
        View view = convertView;
        final Holder holder;

        for(int i = 0; i < mExercise.size(); i++) {
            texts.add(String.valueOf(i));
        }

        if (getItemViewType(position) == 0) {

            if (view == null) {

                view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.item_exercise_header, null);
                holder = new Holder();


                holder.exerciseTitleView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tv_exercice_title);
                view.setTag(holder);

            } else {

                holder = (Holder) convertView.getTag();
            }
            ExerciseSet exercise = mExercise.get(position);

            if (exercise != null)
                holder.exerciseTitleView.setText(exercise.getExerciseTitle());


        } else {

            if (view == null) {
                view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.item_set, null);
                holder = new Holder();

                holder.setCounterView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tv_set_counter);

                holder.cbSet = (CheckBox) view.findViewById(R.id.cb_setdone);

                holder.repsCapt = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.et_reps_number);

                holder.repsCapt.setTag(position); 

                holder.repsCapt.setText(texts.get(position));

                //holder.weightCapt = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.et_weight_number);

                //db = new DatabaseHandler(this.getContext());

                //holder.weightCapt.setTag(position);
                view.setTag(holder);

            } else {

                holder = (Holder) convertView.getTag();

            }
            ExerciseSet exercise = mExercise.get(position);

            /*
             * edit texts
             */
            int tag_position=(Integer) holder.repsCapt.getTag();
            holder.repsCapt.setId(tag_position);

            holder.repsCapt.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

                   @Override
                   public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before,
                           int count) {
                             final EditText repsText = (EditText) holder.repsCapt;

                             if(repsText.getText().toString().length()>0){
                                 texts.add(repsText.getText().toString());
                             }else{
                                 Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Please enter some value", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                             }

                         }

                   @Override
                   public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
                           int after) {
                       // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                   }

                   @Override
                   public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

                   }

               });

            if (exercise != null) {
                holder.setCounterView.setText(String.valueOf(exercise.getSetId()));
            }


            /*
             * check boxes 
             */

            holder.cbSet.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {
                @Override
                public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton button, boolean isChecked) {

                    if(isChecked)
                        mExercise.get(position).setCbChecked(true);
                    else
                        mExercise.get(position).setCbChecked(false);
                }
            });

            holder.cbSet.setChecked(exercise.isCbChecked());

        }

        return view;
    }

    static class Holder {
        public EditText weightCapt;
        public EditText repsCapt;

        // header row items
        TextView exerciseTitleView;

        // body row item
        CheckBox cbSet;
        TextView setCounterView;
    }

}
```

I dont know why, please help..

Edit_1: I tried saving the values into an arraylist and retrieve them while the views are reused but it still gives me duplicated values while I scroll down.

Edit_2: If my question is unclear please let me know!

Edit_3: I placed holder.repsCapt.setText(texts.get(position)) inside the if (exercise != null) { condition and the values are not duplicated anymore. But still if I scroll down and up the values get messed up.

Comment: maybe this `holder.repsCapt.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {` each time a view is recycled it will have the old listener and you add another listener. Basically the answer is Recycled views, you just need to find out what recycling is causing your problem

Comment: You're right Blundell, I just thought maybe it would work because it did with the CheckBoxes, there's a difference I think. I posted the whole class now, would you please take a look at it? maybe you could figure out a fix.

Comment: `Checkbox` is `setOnCheckedChangeListener` and the other is `addTextChangedListener`. Note the subtle naming difference. `set` means set it to this one listener and override the previous listener `add` means add another listener to a list (collection) of listeners

Comment: I see. What do you think I should do exactly? Is there a replacement for the addTextChangedListener that could serve in this case?

Comment: I really can't think of a *nice* answer. How big is your list? If you inflated a new view every time it would fix the issue, see if you have any visible performance loss for this

Comment: It isn't that big, won't be more than 20 views total.

Comment: Can you post an answer about how to do that? Inflate a new view every time.
PS: I managed to prevent the listview from duplicating values, now I only need the views not to get messed up, do you have any idea how to fix that?

Comment: Just don't use the holder pattern - means you always inflate a new View

Comment: same results. A dead end

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to solve my issue after some digging in google, here's the outcome:

```
@SuppressWarnings("unused")
@Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup arg2) {
    final Holder holder;
    convertView = null;
    if(getItemViewType(position) == 0) {
    if (convertView == null) {

        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.item_exercise_header, null);
            holder = new Holder();
            holder.exerciseTitleView = (TextView)               convertView.findViewById(R.id.tv_exercice_title);
        convertView.setTag(holder);

        } else {

            holder = (Holder) convertView.getTag();
        }
        ExerciseSet exercise = exerciseList.get(position);

        if (exercise != null)
            holder.exerciseTitleView.setText(exercise.getExerciseTitle());

     }
     else if (getItemViewType(position) == 1) { 
     if (convertView == null) {
        holder = new Holder();

                convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.item_set, null);

                // reps e.t
                holder.repsCapt = (EditText) convertView
                        .findViewById(R.id.et_reps_number);

                holder.repsCapt.setTag(position);

                // weight e.t
                if(exerciseList.get(position).getExerSave()!=null) {
                    holder.repsCapt.setText(exerciseList.get(position).getExerSave().getReps());

                }
                // t.v
                holder.setCounterView = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tv_set_counter);

                // c.b
                holder.cbSet = (CheckBox) convertView.findViewById(R.id.cb_setdone);

                convertView.setTag(holder);

            }else {
                holder = (Holder) convertView.getTag();
            }

            /*
             * text views
             */
            ExerciseSet exercise = exerciseList.get(position);

            if (exercise != null) {
                holder.setCounterView.setText(String.valueOf(exercise.getSetId()));
            }

            /* 
             * edit texts
             */
            int tag_position=(Integer) holder.repsCapt.getTag();

            holder.repsCapt.setId(tag_position);

            holder.repsCapt.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

               @Override
               public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before,
                       int count) {
                   final int position2 = holder.repsCapt.getId();
                   final EditText repsText = (EditText) holder.repsCapt;
                   if(repsText.getText().toString().length()>0){
                       Save sv;

                       ExerciseSet es = exerciseList.get(position2);
                       if(es.getExerSave() != null)
                           sv = es.getExerSave();
                       else sv = new Save();

                       sv.setSet(position2);
                       sv.setReps(repsText.getText().toString());

                       es.setExerSave(sv);
                       exerciseList.set(position2,es);
                   }
               }

               @Override
               public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
                       int after) {

               }

               @Override
               public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

               }
            });

            /*
             * checkboxes
             */
            holder.cbSet.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {
                @Override
                public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton button, boolean isChecked) {

                    if(isChecked)
                        exerciseList.get(position).setCbChecked(true);
                    else
                        exerciseList.get(position).setCbChecked(false);
                }
            });

            holder.cbSet.setChecked(exercise.isCbChecked());    
        }
        return convertView;
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is surely connected with item views being reused by the list.
So check your conditions and make sure that you provide alternative text in all cases. 
Let's **begin** with item type==0 like this:

```
if (exercise != null)
                    holder.exerciseTitleView.setText(exercise.getExerciseTitle());
```

add

```
else
    holder.exerciseTitleView.setText("debugging: nothing to show");
```

**Edit**
The same is about type==1:
- `holder.repsCapt.setText(texts.get(position))` is called only on freshly inflated view
- `holder.setCounterView.setText(String.valueOf(exercise.getSetId()))` only when excersise is not null

**Edit2**
Well, for **DEBUG** purposes try not to reuse views in `getView()` - **always** inflate right from the start.

If everything becomes OK (or you get some empty fields) then return to my initial recommendation in this post. I **suspect** this scenario

If problem persists than you should pay attention to correctly getting data according to position.

Comment: Actually the problem is the EditTexts with the item type==1. The listView duplicates my editTexts values..

Comment: I placed `holder.repsCapt.setText(texts.get(position))` inside the `if (exercise != null) {` condition and the values are not duplicated anymore. But still if I scroll down and up the values get messed up, do you have any idea how to fix that too?

Comment: Do you have any idea how to stop the values from getting messed up when I scroll down?

Comment: did you mean i have to inflate in the constructor? if that's the case then i dont know how am I supposed to do that, I have two types of views. If not could you please be more specific?

Comment: No, in getView() and ONLY FOR DEBUG. Now you inflate conditionally: if (view == null) {
                view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.item_exercise_header, null); ...