# EditText inside a ListView, messing up values when scrolling down

Tags: java, android, eclipse, android-listview, android-edittext

I have a dynamic ListView which populate data from SQLite database. There is a EditText inside the each row of ListView which used to enter item quantity for each item in the list.
The data is populated correctly in to ListView.
If I enter text in EditText and when scrolling down, the same text appears in the EditText boxes below.

This is the code I used to populate the ListView.

```
    public void AddItemsOnClick(View view){
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    final View layout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_add_items_bulk, (ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.invoicePopup2));
    final PopupWindow pw = new PopupWindow(layout,520,700,true);
    pw.showAtLocation(findViewById(R.id.lroot1), Gravity.CENTER, 0,0);
    final Button bt = (Button) layout.findViewById(R.id.btnTest);

    final ListView lti= (ListView) layout.findViewById(R.id.listAddQtys);
    final SQLiteDB sqlO = new SQLiteDB(layout.getContext());

    sqlO.open();
    Cursor c = sqlO.getStockListForView();
    String[] fromFieldNames = new String[] {"itemname", "qty", "saleprice"};
    int[] toViewIds = new int[] {R.id.tvItemName, R.id.tvOnHand, R.id.tvPrice};

    final SimpleCursorAdapter myCursoeAdapter;
    myCursoeAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(layout.getContext(), R.layout.add_item_list_layout, c, fromFieldNames, toViewIds,0);
    lti.setAdapter(myCursoeAdapter);

    bt.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            pw.dismiss();
        }
    });
}
```

**activity_add_items_bulk.xml**

```
<GridLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context="nanosoft.nanosoftmobilepos.AddItemsBulk" 
android:background="@color/seperator_title_background"
android:id="@+id/invoicePopup2"
android:layout_margin="12dp"
android:columnCount="1"
android:rowCount="2"
android:orientation="horizontal">

<ListView
android:id="@+id/listAddQtys"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="342dp"
android:layout_column="0"
android:layout_row="0"
android:divider="@null"
android:dividerHeight="3dp"
android:smoothScrollbar="true" >

</ListView>

<Button
android:id="@+id/btnTest"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_column="0"
android:layout_gravity="left|bottom"
android:layout_row="1"
android:text="Button" />
```

I am very new to android and an understandable solution would be appreciated.

Thank you!

Update 1: [This solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26513336/listview-edittexts-values-are-messed-up-when-scrolling/26596092#26596092) did not helped me.

Comment: Forget the ListView, use `RecyclerView` for focusable elements.

Comment: check this - http://stackoverflow.com/a/26596092/1479511

Comment: @DroidWormNarendra I tried to use that. but I don't understand how use it.

Comment: I suggest you to debug list adapter & write our Own LOgic code to save filled Edittext Data .....i had faced similar problems number of times i used Hashmap to save and Update My List Results